# Проблема при аутентифицировании пользователя в приложении с помощью VK SDK

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

В своём приложении добавил функцию авторизации через VK SDK, при подключении руководствовался [официальной документацией](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk): добавил зависимости в Gradle, строку в strings.xml и т.д.
Но при вызове Vk.login() через несколько секунд после нажатия появляется данное диалоговое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение вопроса**

***UPD: Лог ошибок***

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.vk.api.sdk.ui.VKWebViewAuthActivity has leaked window DecorView@3bd4bc[VKWebViewAuthActivity] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:770)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:754)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:405)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:373)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1159)
    at com.vk.api.sdk.ui.VKWebViewAuthActivity$OAuthWebViewClient.showError(VKWebViewAuthActivity.kt:200)
    at com.vk.api.sdk.ui.VKWebViewAuthActivity$OAuthWebViewClient.onReceivedError(VKWebViewAuthActivity.kt:176)
    at C9.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-451513133:124)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

***UPD2: код вызова метода регистрации***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    VKAuthCallback vkCallback = new VKAuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLogin(@NonNull VKAccessToken vkAccessToken) {
            Log.d("myl", vkAccessToken.getEmail());
            Log.d("myl", vkAccessToken.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoginFailed(int i) {
            Log.d("myl", "error " + i);
        }
    };
    if (data == null || !VK.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, vkCallback)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<VKScope> permissions = new ArrayList<VKScope>();
    permissions.add(VKScope.EMAIL);

    VK.login(this, permissions);
}
}
```

Comment: А в логах ничего нет? Там, по идее, должна быть ошибка. По скриншоту мало что понятно. Может у вас в манифесте нет разрешения на интернет?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
Данная строчка присутствует в манифесте
Лог ошибки прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Не очень похоже на реальную ошибку... Покажите где и как вы вызываете  Vk.login().

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я из своего основного приложения сделал маленькое, чисто с регистрацией, но там абсолютно идентичный лог ошибок и окно с ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хотел бы отметить то, что поддержка вконтакте заявила, что ошибка в моём коде, а не в их api, но, как видите, лог ссылается именно на их файлы

Comment: Может вы из страны, где VK заблокирован? Коли так - попробуйте VPN на девайс поставить. В коде ошибок не видно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ситуация была ровно в противоположном Я нахожусь в России и тестировал приложение на телефоне с включенным впн, Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь в обсуждении проблемы

Comment: Рад, что проблема решилась)